# Create nested pages-list from MySQL database using recursion with fixed ordering

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

I am trying to create a nested pages-list from data stored in the MySQL database.
I try to do this because users can order the pages (using JS-script nestedSortable) in the way they want and from that array, I can then create a menu with the items in the right order.

My pages have the following data stored:

```
page_id
parent_page_id
ordering
site_id
title
```

I retrieve the following from the database:

```
SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE site_id = '".$iSite_id."' ORDER BY parent_page_id, ordering ASC;
```

If a page does not have a parent, the parent_page_id is 0.

So far so good, but I have a lot of problems understanding how a recursive function works, and because the amount of levels is (theoretically) endless, I can't work around creating this function.

This is what I have so far:

```
$aPagesMenu = $oPage_controller->return_pages_menu($iSite_id);

function create_menu_recursive($aPagesMenu) {
    foreach($aPagesMenu as $aPage) {
        if($aPage['parent_page_id']){
             $aMenu[$aPage['parent_page_id']][$aPage['page_id']] = $aPage['title'];
            //Recursive function call here?
        } else {
            $aMenu[$aPage['page_id']] = $aPage['title'];
    }
    return $aMenu;
}

$aRecursiveMenu = create_menu_recursive($aPagesMenu);
```

I get stuck at trying to understand how the recursive function returns its content into the array of the first level?
How can I understand this and correctly nest one level into another?

I really wish to understand this, because it gives me a lot of delay and issues. Any help is welcome!

**EDIT**

Some data retreived from database:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["page_id"]=>
    string(3) "274"
    ["parent_page_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["menu_ordering"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["page_description"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["page_id"]=>
    string(3) "278"
    ["parent_page_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["menu_ordering"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["page_description"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["page_id"]=>
    string(3) "273"
    ["parent_page_id"]=>
    string(3) "274"
    ["menu_ordering"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["page_description"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["page_id"]=>
    string(3) "275"
    ["parent_page_id"]=>
    string(3) "274"
    ["menu_ordering"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["page_description"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    ["page_id"]=>
    string(3) "276"
    ["parent_page_id"]=>
    string(3) "275"
    ["menu_ordering"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["page_description"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [5]=>
  array(4) {
    ["page_id"]=>
    string(3) "277"
    ["parent_page_id"]=>
    string(3) "275"
    ["menu_ordering"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["page_description"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

This data should then be converted to:

```
273
--> 275
--> 274
    --> 276
    --> 277
278
etc..
```

Comment: Please show data what you getting from query. I will write recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched through older posts on stackoverflow and I think I have found what I was looking for: [PHP Building Recursive Array from List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046364/php-building-recursive-array-from-list)

I have used the following code as recursive function:

```
private function buildTree($itemList, $parentId) {
    // return an array of items with parent = $parentId
    $result = array();
    foreach ($itemList as $item) {
        if ($item['parent_page_id'] == $parentId) {
            $newItem = $item;
            $newItem['children'] = $this->buildTree($itemList, $newItem['page_id']);
            $result[] = $newItem;
        }
    }

    if (count($result) > 0) return $result;
    return null;
}
```

I then called this function with the array I've got from the database:

```
buildTree($aPages, 0);
```

Which gave me the array :D